# If statement based on length of Channel Field

Tags: conditionals, ifelse, parameters, channel-fields

Is it possible to create an {if} statement based on the character length of a channel field? Something along the lines of this:

Lets say I have the channel field - `{title}` and I want to add a class to the parent `<div>` if the character length of the title is larger than 10. Something along these lines...

```
{if "{title_length}" >= "10"}
    <div class="wide">{title}</div>
{if:else}
    <div>{title}</div>
{/if}
```

How would I go about doing this with EE?

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [PHPStringFun](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun) like so:

```
{if {exp:phpstringfun function="strlen"}{title}{/exp:phpstringfun} >= "10"}
    <div class="wide">{title}</div>
{if:else}
    <div>{title}</div>
{/if}
```

If you aren't getting the results you expect check what value is being returned by the plugin by just outputting it in your template like `{exp:phpstringfun function="strlen"}{title}{/exp:phpstringfun}`

[CE String](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string) is an excellent plugin as well which you could use instead of PHPStringFun. Worth taking a look at. With CE String you'd do:

```
{if {exp:ce_str:ing strlen}{title}{/exp:ce_str:ing} >= "10"}
    {title}
{if:else}
    {title}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins with which you can determine a string length.
Here is one: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stringlength

Comment: Link to download the Stringlength plugin seems to be missing from devot:ee. Here it is https://bitbucket.org/fmachine/stringlength